# What happened to the opening prices of the S&P-500 from 1962 to 1982?

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance

I want to look at the prices of the [S&P 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_500), one of the most commonly followed equity indices (roughly speaking, it tracks the performance of the stocks of the 500 largest American companies).

Using the Python library [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) for this, which pulls data directly from Yahoo Finance, I did the following:

```
full_history = yf.Ticker("^GSPC").history(period="max", interval="1d")
```

This gives me the history of the S&P-500 index dating back to the 30th of December, 1927.

However, I noticed the following: When running

```
print(full_history.index[full_history["Open"] == 0])
```

one gets

```
DatetimeIndex(['1962-01-02', '1962-01-03', '1962-01-04', '1962-01-05',
           '1962-01-08', '1962-01-09', '1962-01-10', '1962-01-11',
           '1962-01-12', '1962-01-15',
           ...
           '1982-04-05', '1982-04-06', '1982-04-07', '1982-04-08',
           '1982-04-12', '1982-04-13', '1982-04-14', '1982-04-15',
           '1982-04-16', '1982-04-19'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=5075, freq=None)
```

Indeed, it seems that the opening prices between 1962 and 1982 are all set to 0, i.e. they are missing.

Is this particular to Yahoo Finance, or is there some reason why the S&P-500-opening prices in this time period are unknown?

Comment: You conclude that based on the abbreviated output…?

Comment: I've just run your code in my environment, and I'm getting it from 1927. The number of indexes for the date was 19674.

Comment: When you inspect the raw data what do you see?

Comment: @wwi This is not an issue with my data inspection. The data is missing in the dataframe itself.

Comment: @r-beginners As I have stated in my question, the data goes back to December 30, 1927. The indexes I am printing are only the ones where the opening price is 0.

Comment: @deceze The full output just contains all the dates between '1962-01-02' and '1982-04-19' except for a few exceptions, where the opening price is not set to 0. See also by comment above.

Comment: It's not limited to the API call, you will see the same thing if you look at the history on the Yahoo Finance site. Look at 1970 dates, for instance, and they all say open is 0. (But I don't know why it's like that)

Comment: @DanLowe Actually you are right and there seems to be some issue with the API: [Here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC), Yahoo finance doesn't let you see data before ~1985, but if you click on "full screen" above the chart and scroll back to before 1982, they have non-zero opening prices. Furthermore, the yfinance API doesn't show any difference between opening and closing prices for a long period of time after 1927, while the Yahoo Finance chart does! Very confusing...

Comment: @DanLowe Then again what the hell: When you look at the [raw data by Yahoo Finance themselves](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?period1=-1325462400&period2=399859200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true), there are also many many 0's in the opening column......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the data gives a hint: before 1962, all data columns (OHLC) contain the same value. Only in 1962 do HLC start to differ (with open being 0).

[This article](https://computerhistory.org/blog/tools-of-the-trade-an-historical-look-at-technology-and-commerce/) provides another hint: the first computerized order recording of trades starts to emerge in the early sixties, with the next 'revolution' occurring around 1983. It's purely circumstantial evidence (and I'm not a historian), but there's a clear suggestion of a structural break in the way data was recorded (or even generated!)

Trading back in 1927 was nothing like it is today...

Comment: Yeah, I remember buying stocks in 1927, that was pretty tough ;)